# Webpack2 not parsing sass files

Tags: webpack, babeljs, sass-loader

I'm trying to make webpack to compile and serve scss files. Unfortunately whatever I do and change *.scss files are not parsed. The only thing which is done by webpack is generating a bundle.js file which serves all js content. I'm not really sure what's wrong witch this configuration.

```
let path = require("path");
let webpack = require('webpack');

const ExtractTextPlugin = require("extract-text-webpack-plugin");

const extractCSS = new ExtractTextPlugin("styles.css");

module.exports = {
  devtool: 'inline-source-map',
  entry: [
    './src/index.js',

  ],
  resolve: {
    modules: [
      "src",
      'node_modules'
    ],
    extensions: ['.js', '.jsx', '.scss']
  },
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, "build"),
    filename: 'bundle.js'
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.jsx?$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: [
          'react-hot-loader',
          'babel-loader?presets[]=react,presets[]=es2015',
        ]
      },
      {
        test: /\.scss$/,
        include: path.join(__dirname, 'app', 'scss'),
        use: extractCSS.extract({
          fallback: 'style-loader',
          use: [
            'css-loader',
            'sass-loader?outputStyle=expanded'
          ]
        })
      }
    ]
  },
  plugins: [
    new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(),
    new webpack.NoEmitOnErrorsPlugin(),
    extractCSS
  ],
};
```

With following source tree:

```
ROOT
  /build
  /src
    /scss
    index.js
  webpack.config.js
  packages.json
```

Comment: Did you import/require all the main entry scss files somewhere inside your js code? If not do it. Webpack only test for imported/required files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your .scss files have to be somehow accessible trough an entrypoint, either by being imported/required in `index.js` or (better yet) in a separate file like `index.scss`.